# MySQL: Remove part of string up to the third to last occurrence of forward slash

Tags: php, mysql, database, replace, laravel-4

I've seen JavaScript parses for this, but not any suitable MySQL ... I have a column in my database that contains a string like this:

```
http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/huge_eye-150x150.jpg
```

I need to be able to remove every part of that string except `2012/10/huge_eye-150x150.jpg`

So I need to remove `http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/` ... but keep in mind that not ALL of the rows will contain exactly `http://localhost/mysite/wp-content/uploads/` ... some may contain a slightly different string because of a legacy system ... that's why I thought it might be most appropriate to find the `third to last occurrence of /`

Perhaps you have a better solution? Thank you!

Comment: extract, explode on slash. glue last 3 elements together then update table. not pretty, but i assume this is a one time job

Comment: I appreciate the comment. Can you post an example?

Comment: @dcolumbus did you see my answer?

Comment: i would go with @rsanchez's answer much cleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(url,'/',-3)
```